Deprecation of Transform and TransformForEach methods How to use New way with Front End in Blazor
I was looking at using Transform but it looks like it will be removed soon and a new way with computed properties is to be used.
https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/2072
My question is how do I use this new way when using blazor and the plugins for hooking up the front end like: https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation
// After migration - the transformation takes place inside the model and is exposed via a computed property. 
class Foo 
{
   public string SomeValue { get; set; }
   public int? SomeValueAsInt => int.TryParse(SomeValue, out int val) ? val : null;
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo> 
{
  public FooValidator() 
  {
    RuleFor(x => x.SomeValueAsInt).NotNull().GreaterThan(5);
  }
}

I tried to do this but now my validation on the front end does not work (if I type something in a box it won't trigger).
I think it is because I am hooking up the control to SomeValue and the RuleFor is for SomeValueAsInt so the rule never gets triggered as it's not for SomeValue (I am using havit)
<HxInputText @bind-Value="SomeValue " Label="Name" />

When I use the old transform way that is being removed it would work but of course I won't use it as it will be removed soon.
How should I be doing this?

Maybe this is a contrived example, but why would you not do this the other way round.  The int property is get/set and linked into the input control.  You get the string version with ToString.  Your validation defines that it must be an int greater that 5,

Yes, if I could, i would just start off as an Int but because of some requirements and other tools this is not possible
